# Google Nearby Connection: How to build up a Mesh Network (Android App)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, bluetooth-lowenergy, google-nearby

I am currently writing my Bachelor Thesis and I have to develop an Android App which is building up a Bluetooth (BLE) Mesh Network (probably with Google Nearby Api?).

The app should be used at small events for the staff. They can do things like "something is empty at the bar, runner please come and refill".

The runner is somewhere close to the event location but may not be connected directly to the guy at the bar.

**Q1: How to connect 5-10 devices in a Mesh Network with Nearby-Connections-API & how to handle them?**

**Q2: For example: how can I send a Payload from node 1 to node 4?**

[mesh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mazaJ.jpg)

**Q3: how to handle the multiple connections? and how to reconnect if a device (which connecting bar + runner for example) losing connection?**

I have downloaded the google examples "StoneScissorPaper" but it seems like they just connecting a single device.

I want to use P2P_Cluster as strategy.

Comment: I've answered a couple of this in other stackoverflow posts (especially Q1, Q2). Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51177985/multi-peer-connection-using-google-nearby-connection and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52773197/be-able-to-send-messages-bytes-simultaneous-to-multiple-devices-using-nearby-con

Comment: well I've read these threads before. I was hoping for a code snippet according to the connection class (which is handeling multiple connections).
How do I technically code a broadcast with this API?
I am currently working with this one which is trying to build up the "snake-like"-connection (https://github.com/nSpider/NearbyConnectionMeshNetwork)
Cheers!